# How to get faster result by using this Stored Procedure in SQL server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

please visit my site www.smetiger.com this site is developing only and only one developer this is me.
so please visit it and give me response it is faster or not and i want to share Stored procedure please visit it and give me solution why www.smetiger.com is slow?. Please.

Comment: If you want help, make it easy for us.  Edit your question so that all code shows as code and that only the code that is running is there.  In other words, take away the commented out commands.

Comment: Thanks. for edit suggestion.

Comment: So, sorry, I wont try to even find out what SQL you are really executing. Do that part of your work yourself (or hire a consultant that you pay for that dreaded part of the job). Get a query, get an execution plan, and get rid of all the dynamic SQL in there that just is soooo unnecessary. Just trying to find out what SQL you try to run is more work thatn most people here are willing to do for free.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing so much logic in Store Procedure? Try to move the logic in your business  layer. You are building query dynamically which is always slower as compared to static query which is already complied.

Answer (score 1):

As Brown_Dynamite mentioned, dynamically building and executing your queries inside the stored proc will always be a lot slower. If you don't want to re-write the stored proc, chuck SET NOCOUNT ON; right under the BEGIN.

This will prevent SQL Server from returning execution row counts to the client and squeeze out a little bit more performance.